# NSTimezone how to set CST to nsdateformater

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

all

I'm new to ios programming.
I want to set CST in the method

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:]
```

I have created a sample project to get all known timezones
Code is here:

```
NSArray *timeZoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];

for (NSTimeZone *timezon in timeZoneNames) {

    NSLog(@"%@",timezon);
}
```

It gives the following result:

[Session started at 2011-09-28 09:50:28 +0530.]
2011-09-28 09:50:29.535 Timezonetest[10352:207] Africa/Abidjan

2011-09-28 09:50:29.537 Timezonetest[10352:207] Africa/Accra

2011-09-28 09:50:29.537 Timezonetest[10352:207] Africa/Addis_Ababa

2011-09-28 09:50:29.538 Timezonetest[10352:207] Africa/Algiers

........................

........................

........................

........................

2011-09-28 09:50:29.765 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Pago_Pago

2011-09-28 09:50:29.766 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Palau

2011-09-28 09:50:29.766 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Pitcairn

2011-09-28 09:50:29.767 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Pohnpei

2011-09-28 09:50:29.768 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Ponape

2011-09-28 09:50:29.769 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Port_Moresby

2011-09-28 09:50:29.773 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Rarotonga

2011-09-28 09:50:29.775 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Saipan

2011-09-28 09:50:29.775 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Tahiti

2011-09-28 09:50:29.776 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Tarawa

2011-09-28 09:50:29.776 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Tongatapu

2011-09-28 09:50:29.777 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Truk

2011-09-28 09:50:29.778 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Wake

2011-09-28 09:50:29.778 Timezonetest[10352:207] Pacific/Wallis

Anyone can say which is the name for CST(central Standard timezone) in the above list
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try this by first method u got all time zone after that wat u want u set by key value.

NSLog(@"%@",[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]);

[dateFormater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following code,

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CST"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
NSTimeZone *cst = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT-06:00"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:cst];
```